# PHP imap: if can't connect, just return, but warning message still displaying

Tags: php, warnings

I have a function that tries to grab some emails using the imap library. If it can't connect I would like the function to just return without doing anything else.

```
$imap = imap_open($mailboxPath, $username, $password);
if (!$imap)
  return 0;
```

This works but I still get a PHP warning message that the connection attempt has failed from a timeout. Can I prevent this warning from being displayed?

Comment: Using the `OP_SILENT` option flag as described in the docs should prevent it from issuing that E_WARNING. http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't silence imap\_open error notices in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422405/cant-silence-imap-open-error-notices-in-php)

Comment: Actually based on a deleted answer in the question I linked, OP_SILENT may not actually work for that purpose and you have to `@` suppress the error :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explicitly supress warnings in php, prefix the function you're calling with `@`. Try to do this as little as possible, though.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding @ will suppress all kinds of errors, even fatal errors which terminate script execution. So a simple typo or any other more complicated error can break your script without any notification.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [set_error_handler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) function to define own function responsible for handling different types of PHP errors. If you want to change the way how warnings are handled, your code may look like this:

```
set_error_handler("warning_handler", E_WARNING);

$imap = imap_open($mailboxPath, $username, $password);
if (!$imap)
  return 0;

function warning_handler($errno, $errstr) { 
// don't display the message, maybe write it to log file
}
```

If you just want to hide warnings, you can pass an empty anonymous function to set_error_handler():

```
set_error_handler("warning_handler", function() {});
```

But in this case you will loose any trace of warnings that may occur in your script.

Comment: Instead of linking to an existing answer as an answer, link to it in the comments.